# Can I pass an infinite number of arguments to a generic type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to pass a few arguments, but I get an error from linter: TS2314: Generic type 'FruitKit ' requires 1 type argument(s).

I tried to use something by type ...args, but it also didn't work.

```
interface Apple {
    red: number;
    yellow: number;
}

interface Banana {
    ripe: number;
    rotten: number;
}

interface FruitKit<T> {
    fruits: T
}

interface MyCustomFruitKit extends FruitKit<Apple, Banana> {}

const FruitKit: MyCustomFruitKit = {
    fruits: {
        red: 1,
        yellow: 2
    }
};
```

Comment: try ```interface MyCustomFruitKit extends FruitKit<Apple | Banana> {}```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You use `MyCustomFruitKit` as if it's just `Apple`.

Comment: Try to intersect them, `FruitKit<Apple & Banana>` or pass a tuple to `FruitKit` like this `FruitKit<[Apple, Banana]>` there is no rest parameters syntax for generic arguments like this: `interface FruitKit<[...T]>`

Comment: Also, `infinite` is something we ***`must`*** stay away from ... while programming. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only pass a single type argument to a type that expects only a single type parameter. What you in this case depends on what you want, whether you want `FruitKit<Apple, Banana>` to mean that each property is **both** an `Apple` and a `Banana`, or that each property is **either** an `Apple` or a `Banana`. From your example usage, I suspect you want either/or, which is the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `Apple | Banana`:

```
interface MyCustomFruitKit extends FruitKit<Apple | Banana> {}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAd0BsUG8CwAUMiclBACYBcyIArgLYBG0A3EacgJ4RZYD2Adxr1mbIgF8iRUJFiIUAITggVcZAWKkowdBBGMWUdlpJR+YSCANjjk6YVnR4SZADEodYGADS3gDwAKgB8GhykMJ7eAM40gfaEMuDOCsgAslwAwnTRYPwMHl6+3sgQAB5WFNHuUcVg-hjYKAA+yMqqqqG4UomECPwguTVFfmA0Gdm5+YXeo8gAvGGmyJFFsUucnOTUyACMADThm9y8AsLIAExHyD0SrEA)

(If you wanted them to be both, it would be `&`, [an intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), rather than `|`, and your objects in the usage example would need all four properties [`red` and `yellow` **and** `ripe` and `rotten`].)

---

Side note: I'd avoid having a type and a constant with the same name (`FruitKit`). Although the names live in different namespaces, it's still confusing to the programmer reading the code.